# Is anything known about functions of the type $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{a_n}$, where $a_n$ is an integer sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

Let's assume $a_n$ is strictly increasing. I know if $a_n$ grows too fast, the function has a natural boundary at $|z| = 1$ but I'm wondering if there are any other theorems or sources to look at for functions of this type, especially when $a_n$ grows more slowly?

Comment: This is a power series $f(z)=\sum b_nz^{n}$ where $b_n=1$ when $n=a_n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Do you want only positive integer and strictly increasing sequences?

Comment: Interesting question, for no specific reason, I tried $$\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } (1-\zeta (2))^{fib(i)}$$ which seems to be about $-1.227267688$. And $\zeta (3,4,5) \approx$ -0.3718702096, -0.1584310456, -0.07254227672$

Comment: @clark yes, of course. I'm wondering if there's anything special about series of this type though.

Comment: @Somos yup. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Read [Lacunary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function) for details.

Comment: if $a_n$ is a quadratic polynomial in $n$, you get theta functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

Comment: The series has radius of convergence $1$.

Comment: Only somewhat related, but potentially interesting: $$\prod _{i=2}^{\infty } \zeta (i)^{f(i)} \approx 7.149508611$$

Comment: In particular I'm most interested in $a_n =p_n$, the $n$th prime number, but really this question interests me in general.

Comment: There is a theorem by Pólya-Carlson: any power series with integer coefficients and radius of convergence $1$ is either a rational function of certain form or having a natural boundary at $|z| = 1$.
When your $a_n$ is strictly increasing positive integers and not ultimately periodic, then your function has a natural boundary at $|z| = 1$.

Comment: Really? Thanks for that! Can you give me a link?

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I don't have a link. I learn that from a book [Nine Introductions in Complex Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Nine-Introductions-Complex-Analysis-North-Holland/dp/0444518312) by S. L. Segal.  Look at Chapter 6, Natural boundaries, there for more info.

Comment: Functions of this type are trivially the ordinary generating functions of characteristic functions, i.e. those sequences which are $0$ or $1$ if something is in the set. For example the characteristic function of primes $p$, $\chi(p)=1$ and $0$ otherwise, gives $x^2+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^{11}+\cdots = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \chi(k)x^k$ which is the generating function associated with this sequence.

Comment: When $a_n$ grows as slowly as possible (since you replied "yes" to Somos), I think you just have $x/(1-x)$, so your radius of convergence doesn't change for sequences that grow slowly.